# Ubuntu 10.10 on EEE: how to free up disk space

Tags: ubuntu, netbook, disk-space, ubuntu-10.10

I have an Ubuntu EEE 701, 4GB flash harddrive. It has about 180MB free. How can I free up space? If I remove applications, it doesn't seem to free up space. I do have a 4GB sd-card, but for some reason that card is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same EEE PC and the built-in hdd is painfully small.

One of the best ways to clear up space I've found is to remove the repository cache.  By default, any packages you download gets saved until it's obsolete.

You can clear out the local repository of package files by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

If you use autoclean instead of clean, it only removes packages that can no longer be downloaded (and are mostly useless).

What I've also done is mount my home directory on my SD card for more space.  I would try reformatting the card into fat32 (for cross-compatibility) or JFS (personal preference) with gparted, and then try remounting it again.

Comment: Thank you. The disk was completely full yesterday, nothing worked except ssh which I had enabled luckily enough. Your tip created enough room to get it working again!